# Does anybody know why some journals have "Topical Collections"?

Tags: journals

What does it mean "Topical collection" within a journal? Are the papers published under "Topical Collections" better promoted?

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: I have the feeling it is a way to curate different subfields within the same journal but not sure how they can help authors or researchers. As an example: https://link.springer.com/journal/volumesAndIssues/12665?tabName=topicalCollections

Comment: Why don't you think grouping similar articles under (useful) subheadings is effective to authors or researchers?

Answer (score 1):

These are just ways to allow folks to find articles of interest within larger (less focused) journals.

Good examples are topical collections within a larger Mathematical Biology journal like the Bulletin of Mathematical Biology that correspond to subgroups within the society: https://www.smb.org/subgroups/

I think this will become more and more popular as journals get broader and broader.  Think about a journal like [Nature Communications](https://www.nature.com/ncomms/) that takes science from any field... it's hard to 'browse' this journal in the way that you might browse a journal IN YOUR SUBFIELD, because the vast majority of the stuff is completely unrelated.  In a topical collection however, you might find things of interest.

Comment: A good example is using tags on questions on here ...

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers. They are very useful for me.